# Rails Simple form array text input

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, arrays, simple-form

I am using SimpleForm to build my form.

Having a model with two arrays of decimals, weights[] and repetitions[], I used [this](http://railsguides.net/simple-form-array-text-input/) tutorial to make an input form for each number in these arrays seperately.

My problem is i don't know how to add/remove fields from the form with javascript. The author of the tutorial didn't put any code "because it’s rather trivial task". 
Where and how do i need to put javascript to perform these tasks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well unlike adding nested records, where you need to query rails to create a `new` associated object, this really is just about using javascript to add another input.  I would probably use a help, because it will make your view cleaner.  So you have to create a helper that constructs your input field, call to that helper in your view, use a few lines of javascript to put the data from the helper onto the page where you want it.

## The helper

```
module ApplicationHelper
    def link_to_add_weights(name)
    link_to name, '#', class: "add_weight_fields", :"data-field" => "<input class='text optional' type='text'  name='yourmodelname[weights][]' id='yourmodelname_'>"
  end
end
```

so what this does is takes a single argument, the name you want in the link and sets the input field as a data attribute on the link that is to be generated.

## The javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".add_weight_fields").click(function(){
    $("#weights").append($(this).data("field"));
  });
});
```

The helper is generating a link with the class of .add_weight_fields so you want to trigger your javascript when that link is clicked.  Once that happens, you simply want to append the data from the data-field attribute, in this example I'm using the css idd of weights.

## The view

```
<%= simple_form_for(@yourmodelname) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :repetitions, as: :array %>
  <div id="weights">
    <%= f.input :weights, as: :array %>
    <%= link_to_add_weights "Add New Weight" %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Then you'd do the same fore repetitions.  Create a new helper, create a new js method (or you could make it DRY and use the same method for both with a little conditional), and add some identifying css to the view for the js to find along with another link.